# Replacing Text with Images When Text is Loaded via PHP

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

so I'm currently working in the development of site and I'm wanting to replace text in divs with images, I've seen a few examples on here however they don't repeat for multiple strings of the same text or the javascript loads before the PHP and doesn't change the text.

```
<div class="text">text1</div>
<div class="text">text2</div>
<div class="text">text1</div>
```

I'm needing text1 to replace with image1 and text2 to replace with image2 etc etc. What would the best way to do this ?

I forgot to include that it's a CMS so I don't have access to the PHP directly, just the HTML templates it uses.

Comment: When you say `replace text with images` do you mean you'd like to add to each div `background-image: url()` selector or append a child with `img` tag?

Comment: replace the div entirely with an image would be preferred

Answer (score 0):

This snippet loops over the `.text` elements and gets the `text#` value from each element. Then extracts the number of each text and uses it to create a new image. Whenever the image has been loaded with the correct `src` it will remove the text and replace it with the image.

```js
const textElements = document.querySelectorAll('.text');
for (const textElement of textElements) {
  let text = textElement.textContent;
  let numberOfText = text.split('text').pop();
  const image = new Image();
  image.addEventListener('load', event => {
    textElement.removeChild(textElement.firstChild);
    textElement.append(image);
  });
  image.src = `/image${numberOfText}`;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">text1</div>
<div class="text">text2</div>
<div class="text">text1</div>
```

Comment: Apologies could you add this in a working JSfiddle because I can't get it working on my end

Comment: That's probably because the `src` isn't pointing to a valid URL. You should specify the folder where you keep the images in that string. Check the console for errors if you encounter them.

Comment: I just realized how this works, this wouldn't work for my use because it's not simple text1 or text2 it could be "car" "bike" etc etc

Comment: Well, do the words in the text match the names of the images?